# PHP - Program Logic in allocation of variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic, business-logic

I have 5 Sales people in company website.Now when ever query comes it should be distributed in the following ratio

SalesA :  SalesB :  SalesC :  SalesD :  SalesE  = 1 : 2 : 1 : 1 : 1

I have made my website in php with mysql as Database.

1.Is there a possible way to achieve the above with out using database

2.What would be best db design in case db is needed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Simple I have a Sales Team which has Five Members say SalesA, SalesB, SalesC, SalesD and SalesE. Customer put Enquiry  in my website. When the Enquiry is received it will be allocated as in Below Ratio SalesA : SalesB : SalesC : SalesD : SalesE = 1 : 2 : 1 : 1 : 1 SalesB Should get 1 Enquiry more than other for every new enquiry process allocation. Thats It

Answer (score 2):

This logic must be realized in PHP code not on DB level.

Answer (score 1):

Get the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of six (1+2+1+1+1) for the database ID for the row to be inserted. Then assign the salesperson based on that.

```
// Quick and dirty example
switch($nextId % 6) {
    case 0:
        $salesperson = 'SalesA';
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        $salesperson = 'SalesB';
        break;
    case 3:
        $salesperson = 'SalesC';
        break;
    case 4:
        $salesperson = 'SalesD';
        break;
    case 5:
        $salesperson = 'SalesE';
        break;
}
```

This could also be done on database level by using a `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Could you please suggest Db design for the above

Answer (score 0):

DB Design:

```
teams

id   title  ratio
1    TeamA  1
2    TeamB  2
3    TeamC  1
4    TeamD  1
5    TeamE  1
```

There could be 2 ways to create tables: using relational data or not

```
enquiries

id   team_id enquiry
1    1       something
2    2       something else
3    2       something
4    3       something else
```

In this case you should take care about the team ratio when you insert data into enquiries table.

Sample:

```
SELECT e.id AS enquiry_id, e.enquiry, t.title 
FROM enquiries e 
JOIN teams t
  ON t.id=e.team_id
```

Also you can choose for a non-relational enquiries table

```
enquiries

id   enquiry
1    something
2    something else
3    something
```

For this table you will have to care about the team ratio when you select enquiries

Sample:

```
$teams = array();

$query = "SELECT id, title, ratio FROM teams";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $teams[] = $row;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM enquiries";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

$team = 0;
$i    = 0;
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($i >= $teams[$team]['ratio']) {
        $team = $team == count($teams) ? 0 : ($team + 1);

        $i = 0;
    }

    $teams[$team]['enquiries'][] = $row;
    $i++;
}

print_r($teams);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Effort Thank you so much